# Is there a way to check the type of props based on the component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
type ComponentAProps = {
  a: string;
};

function ComponentA(props: ComponentAProps) {
  return <div>component A</div>;
}

type ComponentBProps = {
  b: string;
};

function ComponentB(props: ComponentBProps) {
  return <div>component B</div>;
}

type State = {
  Component: React.FunctionComponent<ComponentAProps | ComponentBProps>;
  props: ComponentAProps | ComponentBProps;
};

const state: State = {
  Component: ComponentA, // error: property 'a' is missing in ComponentBProps but is required in ComponentAProps
  props: {
    a: 'a',
  },
};
```

How do I get it to check that one of the component types is being used and that the corresponding props type is used?

Comment: If you want to stick with these types, have you tried casting your `State` assignments like `ComponentA as ...` etc?   That is a bit ugly and you may have some better luck with templating state with `State<T> = { Component: ReactFunctionalComponent<T>; props: T; }`

Comment: I'm quite inexperienced with TS so not sure what you mean by "templating"...based on the code snippet though it looks like "generics".  How would this work?  Because the generic type can't be both the props type and the function component?  Although i think in the past minutes i've discovered a react utility for getting the prop types from the component.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [a generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-class-types-in-generics) to assert your type based on which type you pass to `State<T>`

```
type ComponentAProps = {
  a: string;
};

function ComponentA(props: ComponentAProps) {
  return <div>component A</div>;
}

type ComponentBProps = {
  b: string;
};

function ComponentB(props: ComponentBProps) {
  return <div>component B</div>;
}

//introduce a generic type
type State<T> = {
  Component: React.FunctionComponent<T>;
  props: T;
};

const state1: State<ComponentAProps> = {
  Component: ComponentA,
  props: {
    a: 'a',
  },
};

const state2: State<ComponentBProps> = {
  Component: ComponentB,
  props: {
    a: 'a', //a does not exist in B
    b: 'b'
  },
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFBcE8AcFMAIDCB7AttZA7WnwEEAFAJ2WgGd4BeeAb1HngEMAueM8IgS0wHMBuUAF8BYEADMArpgDG4TliRoM2XHgAU0EuVYp0WHPmKkyASlr14RWOAlFM8ADwATTgDcAfNKX7c8PA4B6Fw8RQVAIGARdZQMAISNyKnMQBgAjVnYuXlCRUEkZOQVon3BYjS0yHW8VUoTTZIYrGztHYM9qg3hYwLbQ8JAoOHgAZXBGcFgHABV3JLoUxT0a1gAlWEZZADoAMSlZeUximun3EQZNY1YpnP6vTHY2MYmARlZR8cmjg0IK2ep5hhfXBVJbfAA0Fgu2gaDCYrAA5Ix4RCFoIUcJblgHuwPgAmN5PT4dXDxX5zCxA8AgmIklHnCqsAGwljwRHI%20ABAKMeBOZCwCiYZDgeCwAAenAe3C6FjSCNS8IsaKEIiAA)